# JavaScript Framework For Drawing Fancy Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, dojo, yui

I'm going to develop a site wich involves a lot of charts, Pie Charts, Bar Charts etc..
but i want to make it really user attractive including animation and make it available for mobile devices (ipad, android tablets). I've been looking and the best I have found are YUI, Jquery and Dojo.

could you suggest or mention any strengths or weaknesses of each framework?

Comment: This site is for code questions, not software recommendations.

Comment: its a Framework suggest for development

Comment: Yes, we know. Go read the FAQ.

Comment: What kind of questions can I ask here?
software tools commonly used by programmers

Comment: @Diodeus If I had a question about software recommendations, which website I should ask? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) ?

Comment: Raphaël its very good and i like the fact that is open source!!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend either

- http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ (free with usage restrictions)
- http://www.highcharts.com/ (free for non commercial)
- http://anychart.com/home/ (costs, but is very flexible)

I have used all 3 with success.

Answer (score 4):

We use http://www.highcharts.com/ on our projects. But since i wasn't involved in the evaluating process i can't say much about other frameworks.

Highcharts is Sexy, easy to use, well documented and works in all browsers. I like it:)

Comment: Wow highcharts its pretty amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Also check out Sencha Touch Charts.

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/charts